# Running a Python Script on a server (Does it have to be in /cgi-bin/)?

Tags: python, html, scripting, cgi-bin

Right now I have a script thats

```
http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/foo?var1=A&var2=B
```

Is there a way that I can have it run outside of the cgi-bin directory? Like could I have

```
http://www.example.com/foo/?var1=A&var2=B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Apache you can change the directories that can contain executable scripts with the `ScriptAlias` directive in httpd.conf (or whatever file holds your configuration).

You can also use mod_rewrite to rewrite URLs to point to the scripts you want to execute. Mod_rewrite also allows you to pass variables and stuff in the form of URLs if you like that, e.g.

`www.example.com/foo/A/B/ -> www.example.com/foo?var1=A&var2=B`

Comment: THanks, Jasper! Just what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes.  I'm no expert on this, but I know of a number of frameworks that do exactly what you just did (e.g. Ruby on Rails).  A lot of it has to do with how your server routes URLs. Try looking up the documentation on your server.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. I'm running cPanel, how would I lookup this issue?